# Embedded Yammer Script in SharePoint 2010 CEWP Opens Multiple New Windows with different Yammer Feed

Tags: yammer

I have two Yammer feeds that I need to embed in SharePoint 2010 using CEWPs. Each is on a separate page. The web part is linking to a text file in the Style Library. One of them is working correctly and displaying the feed. However, the other is opening the feed in the web part, but also pops up two windows with the other feed.

Both are embedded using the same script with the correct parameters. The only difference in the two being the "FeedId". Below is the contents of the text files (with the "Network" and "FeedId" parameters changed for privacy).

```
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:800px;width:400px;"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0-azure.assets- 
yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
yam.connect.embedFeed({  
container: "#embedded-feed",  
network: "myNet.com",  
feedType: "group",  
feedId: "1234567"  
});  
</script>
```

Why would one of these cause popups with a different feed and the other work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question and therefore may be deleted from this site. You are best to test the same Embed snippets with the [configuration tool](https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure) and see if you have the same issues. If you do, open a support request from within the O365 Tenant Admin portal so that someone can investigate the issue specific to your environment.

You should also note that SharePoint 2010 uses unsupported Document Modes forcing Internet Explorer to run with a down-level engine. As a result, you can experience many issues.